# How to display individual error messages next to form input fields in PHP?

Tags: php

How to display individual error messages next to empty or incorrect form input fields in PHP? If the form is successfully submitted, how to then refresh the page after a few seconds and redirect the user back to a previous page?

**PHP (Front)**:

```
<form id="application" method="post" action="processing.php" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <legend>Application Form</legend><p>
                <label for="fname">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required="required" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**PHP (Back)**:

```
<?php
    function sanitise_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    require_once ("settings.php");
    $conn = @mysqli_connect(
      $host,
      $user,
      $pwd,
      $sql_db
    );
if ($conn) {
      if (isset($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fname = sanitise_input($_POST["fname"]);
      }
        else {
          mysqli_close($conn);
          header("location:application.php");
        }
else {
          mysqli_close($conn);
          header("location:application.php");
        }
      $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS application (
        fname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)";
      $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
      if (!$result) {
        echo "<p>Error!</p>";
      }
    }
    if (!$conn) {
      echo "<p>Failed!</p>";
    }
      else {
        $sql_table = "application";
        $query = "INSERT INTO $sql_table (fname) VALUES ('$fname')";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (!$result) {
        echo "<p>Error!", $query, "</p>";
      }
        else {
          $id = "SELECT * FROM application ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
          $idresult = mysqli_query($conn, $id);
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idresult)) {
            echo "<p>You are applicant #",$row["EOInumber"],"</p>";
          }
        }
      mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `when the user clicks submit` tells me that you should be using javascript

Answer (score 0):

the question is not very clear, but If I have to assume what are you asking for, is how to dispaly error message in PHP. you can  try:

if (isset(variable_name){

echo "display error: "

}

or

isEmpty(variable_name)
{
echo "display error:"
}

try to specify error clearly...

There are multiple answers in stack overflow, that you can search through...

Comment: no need to answer the question, since the OP has not provided any details such as error prone code, references etc, you can instead point the OP to references in the comments

Comment: Try to construct your question clearly, attach content of php files, HTML , be clear in your question, so everyone on stack overflow will be able to answer

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your input in the comments ive come up with the below code. Modify as you see fit

front.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Front Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">My Form</h1>
        <div style="width: 500px;margin:0 auto; margin-top:5px">
            <form method="POST" action="back.php">
                <?php
                // Explode and convert errors string back into array so we can use methods like in_array()
                $errorsArray = [];

                if(isset($_SESSION['errors'])){
                    $errorsArray = explode(',', $_SESSION['errors']);
                }
                ?>
                <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter a name" />
                    <?php
                        if(in_array('name', $errorsArray)){
                            echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;">Something wrong with name</div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter a Email" />
                    <?php
                        if(in_array('email', $errorsArray)){
                            echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;">Something wrong with email</div>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && empty($_SESSION['status'])){
                        echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;">Some fields have errors</div>';
                    }

                    if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && empty($_SESSION['error'])){
                        echo '<div style="margin-top:10px;">Success</div>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

back.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($name) && isset($email) && $name != "" && $email != ""){
    // Continue with database insertion

    $_SESSION['status'] = 'success';
    echo 'Thanks'; // Echo your html
    header("refresh:5; url=./front.php"); // the 5 is seconds
    die();
} else {
    $errorsArray = [];

    if(!isset($name) || $name == ""){
        array_push($errorsArray, 'name');
    }

    if(!isset($email) || $email == ""){
        array_push($errorsArray, 'email');
    }

    $_SESSION['error'] = 'true';
    $_SESSION['errors'] = join(',', $errorsArray);
    header("Location:./front.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: @thezeroandone its actually quite simple, but before i edit my answer i need to know weather `explode()` and `join()` are an option for you

Comment: @thezeroandone see updated code, that should help you